# Getting two random variables and then comparing them. (java acm)

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

i failed and now i need to take a resit exam. This question was on the  final exam and i feel like similar one will come on resit exam. We cant use our computers on the exam we have to write everything on paper so that was big issue i couldnt understand if im doing it wrong or right. Please be kind while answering because im new at java and i dont want to lose my hope i need to pass.

(i cant remember %100 but this was the main idea)

Q: In this question write two methods. First method should take two random variables. And second method should compare those two random variables and gives the result as higher one.

My solution:

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;
public class RandomGenereratorBaby extends ConsoleProgram {

public RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();{

int x = rgen.nextInt(0,9);
int y = rgen.nextInt(0,9);

}
public char BiggerOneWins (int x, int y){
    if(x>=y){
    return (char) (x)   ;

    }else{
        return (char) (y);
    }
}}
```

Please help me.

Comment: why do you return a char ?

Comment: thats what i exactly did on the exam. as i said writing on paper is harder. sorry for my silly mistake

Comment: an int is larger as a char. So you may have an overflow here `(char) (y);` and `(char) (x);`

Answer (score 0):

So my interpretation of the question says the method should be taking in the variables and storing them, not making some random numbers. So my solution would look something like this

```
public class RandomGenereratorBaby extends ConsoleProgram {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void takeInNumbers(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int biggerOneWins(){
        if(x>=y){
            return x;
        }else{
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also changed the return type to `int` as returning as `char` seemed a little odd. 
This is my interpretation of the question and the answer I would give. I hope that helps

Comment: i understand what you did thank you so much for your answer. But is it wrong how i used the RandomGenerator ? Even if its not usefull here it can be useful on the resit exam.

Comment: @omrfarukc I'd say yes, as you didn't actually create a method to take in the two variables. Your code just creates two random numbers and then has a method that takes in two numbers and compares them. This doesn't seem to do what they ask for in your question.